# Using Python decorators when the class def is in another file?

Tags: python, decorator

Say I have `class myClass` in file myClass.py and I want to be able to invoke `@myClass` without needing to clutter up my file with the myClass code.

Is this doable?

I tried importing `myClass` but it did not seem to work.

Comment: can you show some code ? question is not 100% clear for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import mymodule

@mymodule.myClass
class myOtherClass:
    pass
```